# Trying to use policies in Laravel 5.2, following documentation I still can't get it to work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I looked at documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#controller-authorization and some tutorials online and I am sure that I have done everything right. However I cannot get policies to work in laravel 5.2
I created a policy class

```
use App\User;
use App\Gallery;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
class GalleryPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function saveTitle(User $user, Gallery $gallery)
    {
        return true;
        // return $user->id === $gallery->user_id;
    }
}
```

I registered it in AuthServiceProvider like this

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Gallery' => 'App\Policies\GalleryPolicy',
];
```

Now in my controller i call it like this

```
    $gallery = Gallery::where('hash', $request->gallery)->first();
    $this->authorize('saveTitle', $gallery);
```

And I get this output:
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 HttpException in Handler.php line 107: This action is unauthorized.

Comment: Do you also have public function boot(GateContract $gate) {  $this->registerPolicies($gate);  } in your AUthServiceProvider? Laravel actually suggests to reference the class \App\Model::class ( for both model and policy )

Comment: It looks like it is working? What is not working?

Comment: it seems that I was not logged in and that's why it failed. Silly of me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, your Policy works but you don't catch the exception thrown by the authorize method.

The AuthorizesRequests trait throws an HttpException if the authorization fails. If  you don't catch it, the exception is catched by the exception handler and shown to you as you wrote in your question.

```
<?php

class GalleryController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Example action.
     */
    public function show() {
        try {
            $gallery = Gallery::where('hash', $request->gallery)->first();
            $this->authorize('saveTitle', $gallery);
        } catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $e) {
            // Handle the unauthorized request's response here.
        }
    }
}
```

See trait source for more information: (from 5.1 but mostly same stuff.):

Especially: **$message = 'This action is unauthorized.'**

```
/**
 * Throw an unauthorized exception based on gate results.
 *
 * @param  string  $ability
 * @param  mixed|array  $arguments
 * @param  string  $message
 * @param  \Exception  $previousException
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
 */
protected function createGateUnauthorizedException($ability, $arguments, $message = 'This action is unauthorized.', $previousException = null)
{
    return new HttpException(403, $message, $previousException);
}
```